# CSS won't work as Expected after adding a media query

Tags: css, visual-studio, sorting, overriding

Im new to developing and I recently created my first webpage for a school project. 
The directions were to make the webpage `mobile friendly`.

Before I did my research to find out that its easier to do the mobile portion of the code before the desktop portion, I had already written a perfectly working code for the desktop view.

After researching, I made changes to the code by adding in the mobile friendly code to the beginning of the document, then I added a media query element and followed it with my original desktop code.

Ever since I added the media query to my document, my desktop portion of the code won't run correctly. The dimensions from the mobile-friendly portion are overriding the entire document, causing my desktop half to run incorrectly.

The mobile-friendly portion which is embedded above the media query is working just fine, but the desktop portion has took on the dimensions of the mobile portion. Can someone please help me?

By the way, my meta name tags are inserted correctly and I'm sure that's, not the issue.

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/GBD_313/qdr5veyz/

Comment: Give us your code and what you have tried and we might be able to help you more.

Comment: Paste the relevant code in your question. It also seems we need to see it in action; use one of these websites to easily share your code so it can be debugged: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), [CodePen](https://codepen.io/).

Comment: I keep trying to post the code in my question section. It keeps returning me an error message saying "Your code is not formatted as code"

Comment: I think I just added to the JSFiddle website you recommended. Saved under "Learning to Code"

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/GBD_313/qdr5veyz/

Comment: Here is the link to the code on JSFiddle